# ASP5 - Migrations Folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, projects-and-solutions

ASP5 Web App projects come with a Migrations folder. What exactly is the migrations folder for? As far as I got it is for database migration but how do I use it ? Is it safe to delete it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a feature of Entity Framework and has been for a while. Also known as [Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).

Comment: Is it safe to delete it ?

Comment: If you are not planning on using migrations it is safe to delete. Make sure you configure EF accordingly so it doesn't expect it.